# Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader'

Tags: webpack, babel-loader

I am getting this error, can you please help me.Following are my webpack.config and package.JSON file.My server works fine, but not webpack.I installed Webpack globally but that did not solved this problem.

**===webpack.config file===**

```
var path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
  },
watch: true,
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test:/\.js$/,
      exclude:/node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
      }
    }

  ]
}
```

**===Package.JSON file ===**

```
{
  "name": "reduxApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^3.5.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
    "express": "^4.15.4",
    "loader": "^2.1.1",
    "redux": "^3.7.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: just do npm i -D babel-loader and you should be just fine.

Answer (score 5):

This package allows transpiling JavaScript files using Babel and webpack.

All you need for this task is **add the actual loader and env preset as develop dependencies**:
`npm install -D babel-loader babel-preset-env`

Within your webpack configuration object, you'll need to add the babel-loader to the list of modules, like so:

`module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['env']
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}`